# Adding a table from database with javascript

Tags: javascript, database

I am seeking help trying to add a new table in my third function called `ingredients`. I am not very familiar with javascript so I tried to duplicate code from `newDosage` which is similar to what I need to do. Unfortunately, right now all I see is 0, 1, or 2 and not the actual text from the `ingredient` table. If anyone can help me correctly call the table, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Below is my code. The first function pulls the database, the second function uses the results and the third function is where I have tried to add the ingredient table.

```
function listTreatmentDb(tx) {
    var category = getUrlVars().category;
    var mainsymptom = getUrlVars().mainsymptom;
    var addsymptom = getUrlVars().addsymptom;
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM `Main Database` WHERE Category="' + category +
                  '" AND Main_Symptom="' + mainsymptom + '" AND Add_Symptom="' + addsymptom + '"',[],txSuccessListTreatment);
                  }

  function txSuccessListTreatment(tx,results) {
    var tubeDest = "#products";
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var treat;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        treat = results.rows.item(i);
        $("#warning").append("<li class='treatment'>" + treat.Tips + "</li>");
        $("#warning-text").text(treat.Tips);
        $('#warning').listview('refresh');

        //console.log("Specialty Product #1: " + treat.Specialty1);
        if(treat.Specialty1){
            $("#products").append(formatProductDisplay('specialty1', treat.Specialty1, treat.PurposeSpecialty1, treat.DosageSpecialty1, '1'));
        }
        if(treat.Specialty2){
            $("#products").append(formatProductDisplay('specialty2', treat.Specialty2, treat.PurposeSpecialty2, treat.DosageSpecialty2, '0'));
        }
        }
}

 function formatProductDisplay(type, productName, productPurpose, productDosage, Ingredients, aster){
    var newDosage = productDosage.replace(/"\n"/g, "");
     if(aster=='1'){ productHTML += "*" }
    productHTML+= "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class='productdose'><div class='label'>dosage:</div>" + newDosage + "</div>" + 
    "<div class='productdose'><div class='label'>ingredients:</div>" + Ingredients +
    "</div></li>"
    return productHTML;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for changing the topic but have you tried using PHP to handle the data layer (database) instead of JavaScript?

Comment: You're not querying the `ingredients` table, you're only querying the `Main Database` table.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use PHP since it's a web app. Barmar, can you tell me how to query the ingredients table? I thought everything is being pulled in the first function `SELECT * FROM Main Database`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an argument when you call `formatProductDisplay()`. You forgot to pass in treat.Ingredient.

Change:

```
$("#products").append(formatProductDisplay('specialty1', treat.Specialty1, treat.PurposeSpecialty1, treat.DosageSpecialty1, '1'));
```

To:

```
$("#products").append(formatProductDisplay('specialty1', treat.Specialty1, treat.PurposeSpecialty1, treat.DosageSpecialty1, treat.Ingredients, '1'));
```

Also do the same thing to the similar 'Specialty2' line right below it.